# Printing Tabulator Table Using Wkhtmltopdf ( Error: Warning: undefined:0 TypeError: '[object EventConstructor]' is not a constructor )

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, tabulator

I am trying to convert html that has tabulator table in body but it is show the following error:

```
Warning: undefined:0 TypeError: '[object EventConstructor]' is not a constructor
```

and the wkhtmltopdf does not move ahead.

HTML CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.8.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.8.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function (thisp) {
            var fn = this;
            return function () {
                return fn.apply(thisp, arguments);
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="table"></div>
    <script>
        var tabledata = [
            { id: 1, name: "Oli Bob", age: "12", col: "red", dob: "" },
            { id: 2, name: "Mary May", age: "1", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982" },
            { id: 3, name: "Christine Lobowski", age: "42", col: "green", dob: "22/05/1982" },
            { id: 4, name: "Brendon Philips", age: "125", col: "orange", dob: "01/08/1980" },
            { id: 5, name: "Margret Marmajuke", age: "16", col: "yellow", dob: "31/01/1999" },
        ];

        new Tabulator("#table", {
            data: tabledata, //assign data to table
            layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
            columns: [ //Define Table Columns
                { title: "Name", field: "name", width: 150 },
                { title: "Age", field: "age", hozAlign: "left", formatter: "progress" },
                { title: "Favourite Color", field: "col" },
                { title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", sorter: "date", hozAlign: "center" },
            ],
        });

        window.status = 'print';
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

works fine in browser but wkhtmltopdf stops at:

command: `wkhtmltopdf --debug-javascript --window-status print  --enable-local-file-access tabtest.html table.pdf`

[screenshot of the wkhtmltopdf console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RzBR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are trying to generate a PDF of a table that way? your import tool will probably struggle because Tabulator does not produce a pure HTML table.

There are several features that come built in to Tabulator that may provide a better way for you to get what you want:

#### Built in PDF Downloading

Tabulator does come with a built in PDF Downloader that lets you download the table as a pdf with one simple command

```
table.download("pdf", "table.pdf");
```

Full details of this can be found in the [PDF Download Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/download#pdf)

#### Printing the table

Because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM only the visible rows of the table actually exist, the rest are created and destroyed as you scroll, so printing a table will only get you the visible rows.

If you want to print the whole table then you should have a look at the [Print Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/print) that will take you through how to enable print styling an show the whole table:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    printAsHtml:true, //enable html table printing
    printStyled:true, //copy Tabulator styling to HTML table
});
```

#### HTML Export

If you would simply like an HTML equivalent of the table the the `getHTML` function will return a simple HTML equivalent of the table that you can use in any way you like:

```js
var htmlTable = table.getHtml();
```

Full details on this option can be found in the [HTML Table Export Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update#retrieve-html)